# How do I reset the launcher app?

Tags: launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I checked 'use as default' when choosing the default launcher, but now I can't start ADW.Launcher any more](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6042/i-checked-use-as-default-when-choosing-the-default-launcher-but-now-i-cant-s)

I've installed and set up LauncherPro as a replacement launcher app. How do I reset the phone to use the Android default launcher app?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go into your Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications.  Find Launcher Pro and select it.  Hit the button that says Clear Defaults.

Comment: This has worked before, but today for some reason the Clear Defaults button wasn't enabled. I couldn't figure out any way to reset the launcher so I ended up uninstalling LauncherPro. Not the best method, but it was effective.

Answer (score 3):

Go to settings, applications, manage applications, LauncherPro and click "Clear Defaults"