# I checked 'use as default' when choosing the default launcher, but now I can't start ADW.Launcher any more

Tags: launcher, default-applications, adw.launcher

I installed **ADW.Launcher** on my Galaxy S running Froyo (2.2) to check it out.

When it was installed, **every time I pressed the 'home' button, I got a choice which launcher to start**.

In the end I found this irritating, I choose the default installed one, and checked the '`use as default`' check box.

All fine, but now, I can't seem to be able to start the ADW.Launcher any more.

No icon in my application list and none on my home screens.

**How do I start ADW.Launcher again** ( without re-installing it ). I verified that it is still installed on my device.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to remove the default setting for the Launcher application.

`Menu | Settings | Applications | Manage applications | "All" | Launcher | Clear defaults`

Answer (score 9):

There is an app on the market called [Home Switcher](https://market.android.com/details?id=ymst.android.homeswitcher) (or if your on [Froyo 2.2](https://market.android.com/details?id=ymst.android.homeswitcherfroyo)). It allows you to easily switch or launch another Launcher.

[image: Home Switcher]

Comment: This is a great app, I've used it with my NookColor quite often