# Switching to TouchNooter home from Stock Home

Tags: home-screen, launcher, default-applications, nook-color

So I have just rooted my Nook with TouchNooter.

When I press the home button it asked me which I want to set as the default GO Launcher or Home. I chose Home as the default.

Now, I can't figure out how to get back to the TouchNooter homescren. How can I do so?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [I checked 'use as default' when choosing the default launcher, but now I can't start ADW.Launcher any more](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6042/i-checked-use-as-default-when-choosing-the-default-launcher-but-now-i-cant-s)

Comment: Nook Simple Touch doesn't have the settings options mentioned in the other post.

Comment: @moesef: I recommend editing your question to add a link to that other question and the reason why it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to Settings>Manage Applications> All Applications> then, find & select the Home app--- scroll down, and select "Clear Defaults"

The next time you press your home key, it will give you the same dialog asking which app to use.