# Prerequisites of Installing New Launcher

Tags: launcher

First of all, consider me noob in this launcher thing, as I have never installed any launcher on my Samsung Galaxy S2. But now, I'm thinking to take a plunge and download one, but have no idea what are the requirements for such things.

Mobile Information

- Samsung Galaxy S2
- Model No = GT-19100
- Android Version = 2.3.3

Mobile is not rooted.

Answer (score 5):

There should be no real "requirements" for launchers - as long as they could be downloaded to your phone they should work.

Maybe one ore more functions could be slower on older devices if the hardware is not really new, but the base functions should just work...

Comment: The launcher must support your phone specs -- but that's implicitly included with *as long as they could be downloaded to your phone*, of course, when speaking in terms of *using Google Play* ;)

Comment: I also don't recommend uninstalling the stock launcher. If you ever have issues with your new launcher, being able to go back to stock will be helpful.

Comment: @TimScarborough No i will not uninstall the stock Launcher. Is it required that we have to uninstall the stock launcher before installing the New one.... or is there any application that can be used to keep both and I can switch between one another using that app....

Comment: You can switch back and forth between them.  Android should ask you every time which you want to use, until you set a preference permanently.  Even then, you can go into the settings and switch it back (or just uninstall the downloaded launcher).

Comment: See this previous question about how to switch bac to the default launcher: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6042/i-checked-use-as-default-when-choosing-the-default-launcher-but-now-i-cant-s