# How can I undo the “Do Not Ask Again” for using my home screen wallpaper as my lock screen wallpaper as well?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, lock-screens, home-screen, default-applications

I use an app called "Live Video Wallpaper" or LVW which is basically a live wallpaper that allows you to select a video as your live wallpaper.

I have no problem with it but I accidentally checked the "Do Not Ask Again" option when I was asked whether or not I'd like to use my home screen wallpaper as my lock screen wallpaper too before I pressed no.

Now I have the problem that I can't set my home screen as my lock screen as well. Before, I used LVW as my home then set my Galaxy S2 to use it as my lock screen wallpaper as well but now with the option set to "NO" and the default set to "Do Not Ask Again", I can't do it anymore since live wallpapers normally cannot be set as lock screens (LVW was my way to get around that).

Is there a way I can "Unset" that "Do Not Ask Again" option for using my home as my lock screen wallpaper as well? Sorry if I'm redundant.

Comment: Please click on the [default-application](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/default-application) tag I just applied to your question. This already has been asked several times, so you'll find the answer there.

Comment: I believe you're referring to the similar question about the "Gallery" app. That however doesn't work/apply to my question after testing it that's why I asked this one specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting the default wall paper setting by following these steps (described for Samsung's 4.0; see also [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6042/i-checked-use-as-default-when-choosing-the-default-launcher-but-now-i-cant-s)):

`Menu | Settings | Applications | All | TwWallpaperChooser | Clear defaults`

If you also want to reset the settings of your wallpaper application follow these steps:

`Menu | Settings | Applications | (said application) | Clear data`

Comment: Could you please tell me which application it is? I'm not talking about Live Video Wallpaper as it isn't the problem. The problem I'm referring to is about the "Also use as my lock screen wallpaper" - "Do not ask again" setting.

Comment: If it's not a "default app" thing: Are you using a special lock-screen app? Or could it be your launcher taking care for that setting? In these cases, you might find it within the settings of those apps (instead of the system settings).

Comment: I revised my answer to better address what I think may be the issue.

Comment: Tried checking TwWallpaperChooser and it doesn't have the Clear defaults, cache, data option clickable. TwLauncher on the other hand has Clear data available only, same as the Live Video Wallpaper app(which isn't the problem).

Answer (score 0):

I found this application in Play Store but I'm not sure if it works or not. Just give it a try its safe to use. Here - [DefaultApp Reset](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pxlib.android.defaultappset&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings-->Apps-->**Gallery** (or any other Wallpaper browser app that you have used to set the wallpaper)-->`Clear Data` and `Clear Cache`.